# Neo4J Cypher Query on 5M nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is the basic query I am trying:

```
MATCH (b1:Business),(b2:Business) WHERE ID(b1)<>ID(b2) AND b1.name[0]=b2.name[0]
WITH b1,b2,apoc.create.uuid() as uuid
MERGE (b1)-[d:MCC_NAME]->(b2) 
ON CREATE 
SET d.m_score = 100 
SET d.m_event = uuid 
SET d.m_dt = datetime() 
RETURN count (d)
```

I have also tried to separate the query and run through apoc.periodic.iterate() but in either case the query runs forever and never yields results.  The name property is an array but at present there are only single entries in it, so I tried to simplify by using simple comparison of name[0], but it didn't help.  The database is fairly large, about 5 million nodes.  Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
MATCH (b1:Business)
WITH b1
MATCH(b2:Business) WHERE b1.name[0]=b2.name[0] AND b1<>b2
WITH b1,b2,apoc.create.uuid() as uuid
MERGE (b1)-[d:MCC_NAME]->(b2)
SET …
```

Make sure you have an index set on `name`.
When you do not want to have the edges to be bi-directional, you could do

```
WHERE id(b1)>id(b2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but problem is *both* sides are lists so b2.name is a list also.

Comment: @WarwickMatthews sorry i overlooked that, my main point though is that separating b1 from b2 tends to improve performance.